# Rotating an image around a specified point doesn't work! (Android)

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, image-rotation

I'm rotating an ImageView with postRotate(float degrees, float px, float py), setting px and py to a few differnt values including (0,0) and (imgView.getHeight(),imgView.getWidth()) but it refuses to rotate around any other point than the center. I'm wondering whether it's got anything to do with the fact that my gravity is center in the LinearLayout?

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTraj"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/impactangle" />
```

How I'm rotating the image:

```
matrix.postRotate(degrees,imageView.getHeight(),imageView.getWidth());
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(imageScaled, 0, 0,
                imageScaled.getWidth(), imageScaled.getHeight(), matrix, true));
```

PS I've noticed there are a few similar questions, but none of them have suitable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using a custom `ImageView` where I set the angle rotation.

```
public class CompassImage extends ImageView {
    private float angleRotation;

    public CompassImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CompassImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CompassImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setAngleRotation(float angleRotation) {
        this.angleRotation = angleRotation;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(angleRotation, clipBounds.exactCenterX(), clipBounds.exactCenterY());
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

If you play around with clipBounds you may find that helpful.

Comment: Nope. Still refuses to rotate around any other point than the center.

Comment: Oh no! It works! I just had to call setAngleRotation (obviously). The only problem is, it clips the image around the original boundary. Any ideas how to stop it doing that?

Comment: I guess you need to put this imageview on top of what it is currently. Even though you have overwritten onDraw, it's onLayout remains the same, so it's dimensions and viewport are the same as before, that's why the clippings. I have used this imageView in a RelativeLayout that spanned a bigger area and rotating the ImageView was not a problem as it had enough space to rotate ... I hope it makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

A slight "hack", you could probably adjust the image size using something like Paint.net or Gimp, depending on your OS. That would make the image appear to spin on another point. This solution would be pointless if you are planning on using a lot of images though. [This](http://intransitione.com/blog/create-a-spinning-cube-with-opengl-es-and-android/) is a spinning cube tutorial using opengl.

Comment: It might give you some clues, cant comment on your post yet, lol

Comment: Yeah, this does work but it's not ideal for my situation as I can't have the center of that would-be image at the center of my layout.

Comment: Adjusting your linear layout position would change where your image is being rotated, although it would not change the point around which your image rotates.

Comment: Yeah but surely if you rotate is around 0,0 and then recenter it in the view, it'll just look like it's being rotated around the center, no?