# Rotate ImageView and keep original size

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, imageview

Ok I have tried with many different ways rotating the `ImageView` using `Matrix` but I can't find how to rotate it without changing its size. I'm trying to rotate a circle, literally a purple circle. This is what happens:

When its on 0, 90, 180, 260 it have the correct size, but when the value is any one between those the image change it size.

Like 0-45 it gets smaller 45-90 it gets bigger until it reaches original size. I know that its doing it because even that the image is a circle its really a square bitmap.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Maybe this link will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938875/rotating-an-image-around-a-specified-point-doesnt-work-android/16939112#16939112

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17345178/1777090

Comment: I tried with animations, but the image get back to original degree. I don't want to make it rotate without stopping. but to rotate it 12 degrees every 10 seconds.

Comment: Well I solved it with the link that @TheReader gave me

Answer (score 0):

What minimum API are you using ?
From 11, you can use [SetRotationX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotationX%28float%29), it should rotate the view without affecting the image.