# how to rotate imageview from its centre position

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i want to move my `Imageview` from its center position. that one side of `imageview`goes above and after this the other side of `imageview` should comes down 
centre of `imageview`always fix. how to do this my code is

```
imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(80, 90, imageView.getWidth() / 2, 400);

            animation.setDuration(400); // you may  set another duration
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            imageView.startAnimation(animation);

        }
    });
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pati" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pativertical" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pativertical" />
```

like scale type
which type of animation i do this job...

Comment: Maybe [this similar link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16939112/1051783) will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setDuration(500);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setFillAfter(true);

image.startAnimation(anim)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setDuration(500);
anim.setFillEnabled(true);
anim.setFillAfter(true);

image.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this..
You can save this as xml file(image.xml) in res/drawable folder and where you want to rotate imageview then include this line android:src=@drawble/image.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%" 
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360" 
android:drawable="@drawable/prgbar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1- One must check width and height of the imageview, if Height > width then at the time of rotation width must be equal to height and same with height.

2- Make width and height equal to fill_parent and then rotate/translate/scale via matrix.