# how to rotate imageview from its centre position using object animation

Tags: android, android-layout

[I am doing same as this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608073/how-to-rotate-imageview-from-its-centre-position)

This is work fine but I want to move other images as well when image is move
like this

[image: i want to move left side image attach with above image]

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pati" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pativertical" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pativertical" />
```

Comment: what the issue, apply the same animation in all three of them?

Comment: i set my layout where images are android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
and android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
when it animate then why my images layout imageView2 and imageView3 not follow imageView1...????

Comment: Put your code for animation here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for object animation:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvBorder, View.ROTATION, 60);
anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
anim.start();
```