# How to rotate animation with object animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to rotate image that other images also move with respect to animated image

XML is:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pati" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pativertical" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/top_pativertical" />
```

Java code is like that:

```
imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0,45 , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setDuration(500);
            anim.setFillEnabled(true);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            imageView.startAnimation(anim);

        }


    });
```

I want to use object animation, here i use rotation animation which not move actual position of imageview
how can i use object animation..

Answer (score 1):

```
   final ImageView mytrain = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.train);
   final Animation traintween = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.treinanimation);
   final Animation trainfade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.trainfade);
   AnimationSet s = new AnimationSet(false);//false mean dont share interpolators
   s.addAnimation(traintween);
   s.addAnimation(trainfad);
   mytrain.startAnimation(s);
```

this example is set to apply  multiple animation on one image..

Answer (score 0):

create this xml file and set this file in imageview in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loading"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

Comment: Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation);
    imageView.startAnimation(anim);

exception come on animated-rotated

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: animated-rotate

Comment: RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(700);

// Start animating the image
final ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
splash.startAnimation(anim);

// Later.. stop the animation
splash.setAnimation(null);

Comment: from this code my actual view is not move
i want to move my actual view that other images which are imageView2 and imageView2 also move with respect to imageView1
i want to do rotation animation functionality with object animation that my actual view also change there position

Answer (score 0):

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(700);

// Start animating the image
final ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
splash.startAnimation(anim);

// Later.. stop the animation
splash.setAnimation(null);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609145/how-to-rotate-imageview-from-its-centre-position-using-object-animation?noredirect=1#comment30841599_20609145

in this link see image
i want that my left image goes above (link with other image) and other come down so what can i do
my layout also set imageview2 and imageview3 below imageview1
so when it animate then why imageview2 and imageview3 are not below imageview1